# Display a Pdf using Struts2 in a Jsp

Tags: struts2

My problem is i am not able to display the pdf generated on jsp using Struts2.

I am able to generate the pdf dynamically using Dynamic Jasper in struts2 and also able to

download it using the

result type="stream" the only problem i am stuck at is displaying the pdf in jsp. i able to

display it using iframe tag but it display the old pdf not the one i generate at runtime.

if anyone has any suggestions do help me out thanks in advance

Comment: Problem Solved just had to give inline in Content Disposition

Comment: You can post your solution here so that it will help other SO users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Action Class 

public class GeneratePdf extends ActionSupport
{
    public InputStream inputStream;
    File file = new File("D:\\workspace\\desktopApp\\HRIS_Updated\\WebContent\\Jasper\\hris.employee.report.AwardReport.pdf");
    public String execute(){

            try {

            inputStream = new DataInputStream( new FileInputStream(file));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return SUCCESS;
}
public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }



public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

in the .xml file

```
<action name="GeneratePdf" class="hris.report.action.GeneratePdf">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="test.pdf"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Hope it Helps :)